# Use CSS to move a button in html page

Tags: html, css

I have the following button in html code:

```
<button type="button" id="acp-toggle-toolbar" class=" toolbar-left" style="top: 25px;"><img src="https://apostolosloukas.org/wp-content/plugins/accessible-poetry//assets/icons/access.svg" alt="Accessibility Icon"></button><div id="acp-black-screen"></div>     <style>#acp-toggle-toolbar{top:25px;}</style>
        <div id="acp-toolbar" class="acp-toolbar acp-toolbar-skin-1 toolbar-left" aria-hidden="true">
            <button id="acp-close-toolbar">
                <span class="sr-only">Close the accessibility toolbar</span>
                <span class="acp-close-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
            </button>
```

I need to move the button down.

I tried the following with no luck.

```
.toolbar-left img:style {
    top: 105px;
   }
```

My website is https://apostolosloukas.org/ and it's the accessibility button on the upper left.

Comment: what is `:style`?

Comment: Do you want to move the `button`  or the `img`???

Comment: @connexo Isn't it the same in this example?

Comment: Move the element you want to move, and nothing other than that. You want to move the clickable element, not only the visual representation it contains.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `!important` to override inline styles:

```
.toolbar-left {
  top: 105px !important;
}
```

**This is widely considered bad practice and should only ever be used in situations where no other way of solving the problem is available.**

On top of that, the current `top: 25px` affects the surrounding `button`, not the `img`.

The other issue is that there is no pseudo selector `:style` in CSS. Just get rid of it.

This is the result of my suggestion:

[image: Effect of top: 105px !important]
[image]

Comment: I tried it but it does not work. Do you think that the space in class name may affect it?

Comment: I tried it on your website and the screenshots clearly prove that **it does work**.

Comment: Yes you are right! I removed `img` from `CSS` and it's working! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2):

You have inline-css that says: `top: 25px`, this is overriding your class code. In order to fix this, remove the inline css.

You can also add `!important`, in your class code.

Comment: I'm using a `wordpress` plugin and adds this. Is there a way to remove it though `CSS` ?

Comment: You could edit the in-line element directly, but the only other way is using javascript

Comment: @zinon use `!important`

Comment: Without `imporant` even removing the inline styles won't work. Please note that these also don't target the `img`. There is also `style` **tag** which would need to be removed because the `id` selector is more specific: `<style>#acp-toggle-toolbar{top:25px;}</style>`